# How to remove comma separator from price in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I want to show my Price like 1000. Now, i have a price like 1,000 on my website.

How i can remove comma separator from price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prices format are depending of Locale, so you can choose a different locale (language).
Theses locales are defined in Magento lib, so it is not recommended to touch it.

But anyway it is located in :  lib/Zend/Local/Data/en.xml (choose the file that correspond to your locale)

Don't forget to flush cache